# How to prove the following two optimization problems are equivalent?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

The first problem is
$$\min_{\mathbf{x}\subset\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}}\|\mathbf{x}\|_1-0.3\|\mathbf{x}\|_p\quad\text{s.t.}\quad\|\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|_2\leq\varepsilon$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are fixed matrix/vector.

The second problem is
$$\min_{\mathbf{x}\subset\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}}\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|_2^2+\lambda(\|\mathbf{x}\|_1-0.3\|\mathbf{x}\|_p)$$

Comment: This seems like an assignment problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1**:

> What is the Lagrangian function of the first problem?

**Hint 2:**

> What are the KKT conditions of that Lagrangian?

**Hint 3:**

> How do the optimal solutions to both problems correlate?